# Why do I have to cast the returned value?

Tags: java, generics, casting

To me it seams that the function I call already returns the type I have to cast it to. Why do I have to do that?

```
T[]leftPart=(T[]) sort(copyOfRange(a,0,middle));
```

The method copyOfRange that I created supposed to return the same type as the parameter a.

Here is the code:

```
    static public   <T extends Comparable<T>> Object[] sort(T[] a){
    int middle=a.length/2;

    T[]leftPart=(T[]) sort(copyOfRange(a,0,middle));
    }

static public<T> T[] copyOfRange(T[] original,int from,int to){
    int size=to-from;
    T[] retObject=(T[])new Object[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) retObject[i]=original[from+i];
    return retObject;
}
```

Comment: `sort` is declared as returning `Object[]`, not `T[]`.

Comment: I reduced the title to the core problem and moved the rest to the question statement. Try to keep the question title concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`copyOfRange` returned `T[]`, but you put it in `sort()` and `sort()` returned a `Object[]`.